# Return all data when bind variable in WHERE is NULL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a Text Field that users put a year into i.e. `:the_SCHEME_YEAR`.   The user then gets the data for that year.  However when the user leaves the Text Field blank I want to pull all the years back.

This is the code I have developed but cannot get all the years back when `:the_SCHEME_YEAR`,  is left blank by the customer.

```
AND the_year in NVL(:the_SCHEME_YEAR, to_char( '2005,'||'2006,'||'2007'))
```

Any tips would be helpful.

```
SELECT the_year
     , ent_type
     , SUM (a.no_of_parts) number_ents 
     , SUM (ent_value * a.no_of_ents) value_ents
  FROM TEST_REGISTER A
 WHERE the_year > 2004 and the_year <= the_max_year
   AND ent_type is not null
   AND the_year in NVL(:the_SCHEME_YEAR, to_char( '2005,'||'2006,'||'2007'))
 GROUP BY the_year, ent_type
 ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
AND (  (:the_SCHEME_YEAR is null and the_year in (2005, 2006, 2007))
    OR the_year = :the_SCHEME_YEAR
    )
```

(Note that the SQL `in` operator requires a list of values, not a concatenated string of them.)

Comment: Take a bow Tony.  I've been F****g about with radio buttons, LOVs and knew there had to be some SQL that code do the job. Thank you very much.